# Windows: Can no longer find BeautifulSoup when double-clicking python file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, virtualenv

For years now I've been using a python script from my Windows box that uses BeautifulSoup and requests to do bit of web scraping to return some running race results for my club.  A long time ago, I installed Python 3.x and did a pip install of BeautifulSoup4, things just worked.  I would double-click the script -- or run from a command prompt with custom arguments-- and all would run well.

This thing has worked perfectly for years.

Unfortunately I seem to have messed up the install lately. Now when I run it from the command line, I get this:

```
D:\Dev\Srr>srr_new6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Dev\Srr\srr_new6.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4

D:\Dev\Srr>
```

But if I try to install beautifulsoup4 it tells me it's already installed.

```
D:\Dev\Srr>pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\program 
    files\python36\lib\site-packages

D:\Dev\Srr>
```

When I installed python I was sure to put it in the system path.  And when I check the path from my command prompt, there it is.   If I type "python" from the command line, I do get the interactive environment.  And I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling both python and beautifulsoup it did not appear to help.

Googling I've found mention of "virtualenv" so it sounds to me like I need to "activate" that but cannot seem to find or invoke it.  Windows doesn't know about it when I type it from the command line.

Is there some simple way that I can fix this?  Is there some way to make beautifulsoup4 be a part of the "default" virtualenv on Windows so that windows will always find it?

(I'd love to learn python.  I've been saying that for years.  But this isn't for work and there always seems to be other things I need to learn first for work)

Comment: try 

pip uninstall beautifulsoup4 and

pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Sadly that does not help

Comment: I have never encountered such a problem but you can try these ways, Download the python installer again(with the same version you use) There should be "repair" option which you could try, or you can try building from the source like downloading the beautifulsoup4 and installing it like setup.py install